# Test if a Time is the next day, not including midnight

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, .net-4.5

This question answers the question how to check if one `DateTime` is the next day to a another. But, it will be triggered also in the case that midnight tonight is passed, and I want that special case to count as the same day.

I came up with:

`if(secondDate.Date > firstDate.Date && secondDate != secondDate.Date){...}`

This checks if the second date *has* a time component which is a slight shortcut to check for midnight but it feels slightly clunky. Is there a neater/more intuitive way?

Comment: if you want to improve your code, consider posting it to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: This seems to return true for any secondDate that is bigger that firstDate and has time component, not only for the "next day".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
if(secondDate.Date == firstDate.Date.AddDays(1) && secondDate.TimeOfDay != TimeSpan.Zero)
```

Comment: OK so same basic principle check the date and time components separately, just you address my "next day" Vs "later day" bug and your 2nd check is slightly more obvious what it is doing

Comment: Yeah. I don't think it is possible to check it in one condition. "Later day" and not midnight could be with `secondDate > firstDate.Date.AddDays(1)` but for "next day" I couldn't figure one simpler solution.

Comment: @Mr.Boy put this code into extension method `IsNextDayAfter(this DateTime secondDate, DateTime firstDate)` and use it like `if (secondDate.IsNextDayAfter(firstDate))`

Comment: I'm slightly confused about how DST factors in here... if we compare number of days it would be OK?